# C++ templates problem: convert to null

Tags: c++, templates

I have a Stack container class and I want to create instances of various types of Stacks. so I do this:

```
template <typename T>
class MyStack
{
.
.
   T Pop()
   {
      if(!IsEmpty())
      {
         return data[top--];
      }
      else
      {
         return NULL; // I got error here
      }
 .
 .
}
```

When I try to use Stack like this:

```
MyStack<GraphNode> blacks;
GraphNode t = blacks.Pop();
```

I got this error:

```
conversion from ‘int’ to non-scalar type ‘GraphNode’ requested
```

But when I use a pointer type like `Stack<GraphNode*>` there is no problem. I know that `NULL` is `0` and I understand why error occurs... What is the elegant way to tell program that there is no data to return without changing the code? should I add something like an implicit type conversion operator to class? how?

**NOTE:** I'm not using STL

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return NULL from a method in a Template Class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392869/how-to-return-null-from-a-method-in-a-template-class)

Comment: +1 Duplicate but hardly warrants a downvote. It's a well formulated question.

Comment: The downvote was for attempting something which is bad design, and should be avoided completely - "without changing the code?". No need to be obsessed - downvote is just a downvote, a personal opinion, it is not "wipe him from the face of Earth".

Comment: @Suma: Why does that warrant a downvote, instead of an answer that explains why it's bad design?

Comment: Your questions shows following which I think goes against good desing: 1) you are not using STL. Why? (There might be reasons, but do you have some?) 2) You request something implemented without "changing the code". Why? As answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798578//4798617#4798617, the best way to solve this is to change the code, or to use exceptions.

Comment: @Suma: I'm not using STL because I'm learning Data Structures and I can't give my TA a STL library! It's my homework and I want to learn design methods and basically want to learn c++ . 2) I don't have enough time. tomorrow I will give her my homeworks.

Comment: throw exception, of course, that's why they are in the languge

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By returning a `T` by value, the contract of your function is that you *will* return a value. The two alternatives are to change the contract of your function (e.g. return a `T*` instead) or to fail to return by throwing an exception.

Personally, I think that it is acceptable and appropriate to throw an exception in this case. Returning a pointer, or talking a reference to overwrite and returning a boolean success value are both less clean solutions.

Especially if you provide a public `IsEmpty()` method there is no reason to choose a less clean solution. Clients that don't want to handle exceptions can make use of `IsEmpty` to avoid receiving the exception which becomes the equivalent of an assert.

Comment: Or, if calling Pop on empty stack can be considered an error of programmer (interface used against contract), you might want to consider using assert.

Comment: @Suma: You commented just as I was updating my answer; I agree, it's a valid approach.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to return a pointer. I have to not use exceptions :-)

Comment: @SorushRabiee: Are you going to return a smart pointer or manage the lifetime of the pointed-to object some other way? (I think this is a poor design choice, you could omit the exception throw and still return by value, leaving calling `Pop` on an empty stack as undefined behaviour.)

Comment: I don’t like this false dichotomy. There are lots of different ways, e.g. returning `bool` and passing the actual result value by reference (but yuck!), or returning an `option<T>` value (implementation left as an exercise for the reader) or returning a `pair<bool, iterator>` as done by the `map.find` method, just to name a few examples. Personally, I favour the `option` method, of course.

Comment: @Charles: I'm going to return a `T*`. is this wrong? the T is always alive. `data` is a normal array and I never delete it.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Are you addressing the "I'm going to return a pointer. I have to not use exceptions" comment (which I agree is a false dichotomy) or my answer where I provide three options and recommend the exception variant?

Comment: I think the exception solution is the cleanest.  There is no way that this implementation of stack can promise that objects of type T will not throw an exception in their default constructor, requiring only T objects that do not is a pretty restrictive contract.  This means that users of `Pop` will have to handle exceptions anyway.  There is a reason the STL stack template has `front` and `pop` as separate operations.

Comment: @SorushRabiee: It's an approach, but what if someone pops a value and pushes a new one, if they retain the popped pointer are they going to expect to retain a pointer to the old value?

Comment: I would also choose an exception, but maybe it's just that I like things to really blow up when I do something wrong. Or the option type perhaps, frankly that might be best. It more or less forces people to check the return value anyhow.

Comment: @ Charles: Oh! your right... so, without using exceptions, what is solution?

Comment: @SorushRabiee: The simplest solution is to return a value and to simply not handle the empty stack case, making sure you document the fact that clients must not pop from an empty stack.

Comment: @SorushRabiee: Another alternative is to return a smart pointer (e.g. `shared_ptr`) to a dynamically allocated copy or `NULL` if the stack was empty, or return a `boost::optional<T>` as @KonradRudolph suggests.

Comment: @Charles I was referring to your answer: “The *two* alternatives are” (emphasis mine).

Comment: @KonradRudolph: OK. That's not a false dichotomy. That's a true one. The only way to not return a value without changing the signature of the function (i.e. the expression of the contract) is to throw an exception (OK, not strictly, but entering an infinite loop or calling `abort` are all extreme alternatives). The alternative, to change the signature, can be done in a number of ways but all of them (including returning an `optional<T>`) are IMHO a change of contract.

Comment: @Charles ok, I completely misunderstood that part.

Answer (score 5):

The STL `std::stack` splits this functionality into `top()`, which returns a reference to the last element, and `pop()`.  The behaviour is simply undefined if you use either of these and the stack is already empty (i.e. if `empty() == true`).  This doesn't sound like a bad approach.

Answer (score 3):

The canonical pop function returns void for this exact reason. Also, you didn't call the destructor of data[top], which is Bad™.

If in doubt, check the [STL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2zxx282%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Not to mention that unless `data` is a statically sized array on the stack, there's a massive memory leak here.

Comment: No, the reason for returning void is (according to old man Stroustrup in TC++PL) to prevent an unnecessary copy when possible. `back` will fail silently if no element is available, so this is *no* reason not to return by value.

Answer (score 3):

If you haven't read [GoTW #8](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/008.htm), you should do so now. It's devoted entirely to the question at hand -- how to design a stack. One of its most basic points is that the design you're currently using for `pop` *can't* be made exception safe.

The answer it gives to the question at hand (not necessarily a good one...) is to return a default-constructed T if the stack is empty:

```
T Pop()
{
  if(!IsEmpty())
  {
     return data[top--];
  }
  else
  {
     return T(); // No more error
  }
}
```

The problem with this is that in *most* cases, attempting to pop an empty stack indicates a logic error, and should not be allowed to proceed at all. You can debate endlessly between using an `assert` or throwing an exception, but there's rarely a value you can return that's really helpful (a possible exception being returning a NaN if you're dealing with F.P. numbers).